# Regular expression to match a string with 10 digits, starting with specific numbers

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I'm using pyspark RLIKE method. What is the regular expression to match the following formats? The string should always have 10 digits starting with one of the followings:

```
111xxxxxxx
115xxxxxxx
222xxxxxxx
995xxxxxxx
9991xxxxxx
9992xxxxxx
99999xxxxx
```

The string can also start with zeros, in that case it only needs to check for having 10 digits in total:

```
0000xxxxxx 
000000xxxx 
00000000xx
```

I tried `^(111|115|222|995)\d{7}$` which only works for a few of the formats in the list.

Comment: Please be more specific what "only works" and what not

Comment: @JanStránský It is clear that the last three `9991...`, `9992...` and ``9999...`` are not matched.

Comment: try: `^(?=0|111|115|222|995|9991|9992|99999)\d{10}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^((111|115|222|995)\d{7}|999[129]\d{6}|0\d{9})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1fp8rB/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E((111%7C115%7C222%7C995)%5Cd%7B7%7D%7C999%5B129%5D%5Cd%7B6%7D%7C0%5Cd%7B9%7D)%24):

[image]

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start of a group:

  - `(111|115|222|995)`
  - `\d{7}` - seven digits
  - `|` - or

    - `999` - `999` string
    - `[129]` - `1`, `2` or `9`
    - `\d{6}` - six digits
  - `|` - or

    - `0\d{9}` - `0` and then any nine digits
- `)` - end of a group
- `$` - end of string.

**Alternative solution:**

If you restrict the string length using a positive lookahead at the start, the regex will become much more maintainable:

```
^(?=\d{10}$)(111|115|222|995|999[129]|0)\d+$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1fp8rB/2). So you control the total length at the start of the pattern, then you are free to add any more restrictions in the consuming pattern part.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=\d{10}$)` - the whole string can only be a ten digit string
- `(111|115|222|995|999[129]|0)` - All allowed prefixes: `111`, `115`, `222`, `995`, `9991`, `9992`, `9999` or `0`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.